# How do I properly use papi_native_avail to get network performance monitoring events on a BG/Q system?

Tags: c, performance, papi

I'm trying to gather network performance counter data on a BG/Q system with a BG Torus interconnect. I'm using PAPI as this seems to be the most recommended way of doing it, with the other option being the bgpm library, which I don't think is installed on this system. (`locate bgpm` didn't give me anything.)

I'm trying to get the names for all the counters available on the system. so I run `papi_native_avail`, which returns a bunch of events. For example, here is an excerpt from the net category:

```
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| net:::ib0:rx:bytes                                                           |
|            ib0 receive bytes                                                 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| net:::ib0:rx:packets                                                         |
|            ib0 receive packets                                               |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| net:::ib0:rx:errors                                                          |
|            ib0 receive errors                                                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

`papi_native_avail` segfaults but I don't think that is relevant.

So my understanding at this point is that I should be able to use an event name and get an event code from it using `PAPI_event_name_to_code()`, but this doesn't seem to work. I'm guessing these aren't the event names that that function expects. So can someone explain:

1. Where can I find all network events for BG/Q?
2. How do I get the codes for those events?

For completeness, here is  my code and the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <papi.h>

int main(){
  int code = 0;
  int ret = 0;
  PAPI_library_init(PAPI_VER_CURRENT);
  ret = PAPI_event_name_to_code("net:::ib0:tx:fifo", &code);

  if(ret != PAPI_OK){
    printf("Error in getting code\n");
  }
  printf("code: %d\n", code);
}
```

Output:

```
Error in getting code
code: 0
```

Comment: Does PAPI document support for BGQ network counters? In any case, I always preferred Bob Walkup's tool instead.

Comment: [This paper](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/news_pub/submissions/PAPI-for-BGQ_mccraw.pdf) seems to say that PAPI should be fine for this. Which tool are you talking about?